# How to unload native DLL (loaded using [DllImport()] attribute) from SQL Server process?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I have created a SQLCLR User-Defined Function which calls a native C++ DLL.

The native C++ DLL is mine and if I want to make changes in it I need stop the `sqlservr` process to copy the new one. In production that is not acceptable.

Even if I drop the assembly which makes use of that DLL, the file is still in use.

What can I do to overwrite the native DLL?

EDIT

DLL method declaration:

```
[DllImport("Library64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr GetTiming();
```

MS seems to load library on first call to it, and seems to unload when process terminates .... :)

Comment: Since the native DLL is yours, I suggest you rewrite it as managed code.  That will allow you to load the code into SQL Server as an assembly instead of unsafe external reference and avoid this issue.

Comment: I wouldn't get speed of the algorithm in .NET as I have in c++.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2682b53-12ad-4719-b05c-df1476cb39c9/how-to-unload-a-dll?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the "reference" is being held by the App Domain. You can try unloading the App Domain which should clear that out (best guess as I have no way to test this). You can do that by making any security changes to the database. The following works:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE {db_name} SET TRUSTWORTHY ON (or OFF if already ON);
GO
ALTER DATABASE {db_name} SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF (or ON if already OFF);
GO
```

Keep in mind that this will unload all AppDomains in that particular Database. This is usually not an issue since people rarely have multiple App Domains in a single Database (that would require Assemblies being owned by different Users, and most people just use `dbo`).

---

To see what App Domains exist and which assemblies are loaded into them, run the following:

```sql
SELECT DB_NAME(dca.[db_id]) AS [DatabaseName], dca.*, '---' AS [---], dcla.*
FROM sys.dm_clr_appdomains dca
INNER JOIN sys.dm_clr_loaded_assemblies dcla
        ON  dca.appdomain_address = dcla.appdomain_address
WHERE dca.[db_id] <> 32767;
```

If nothing is returned by that query and you still can't replace that external DLL, try the following (which seems like a bit much, but we need to know if it works before trying anything else):

```sql
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 0;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
```

---

Two other options to try are:

- Create a wrapper DLL that you would call via DLLImport. And it would call your Library64.dll
- The last resort would be to forcefully remove the unmanaged DLL with yet another unmanaged call. You did not create the DLL using `LoadLibrary()`, but you should be able to get a reference to it using `GetModuleHandleExA()` and then using that handle in a call to `FreeLibrary()`. This is described in the following blog post: [PInvoke Library Load/Unload Behavior – Freeing Unmanaged Libraries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2004/11/12/256199.aspx).  **It seems this was the only method to be successful. Please see @John's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290350/how-to-unload-native-dll-loaded-using-dllimport-attribute-from-sql-server/32305648#32305648) for the specific code.**

Comment: Well unfortunately it doesn't work. After OFF and ON still I cannot delete the native dll ...

Comment: @John I just added a query to show what App Domains and Assemblies are currently loaded. Please confirm that nothing in that database is loaded after setting TRUSTWORTHY OFF and then back ON again. Could there be another DB with a reference to it? I also posted the query to turn CLR integration OFF and back ON again. I would think that if nothing else,_that_ would remove any references. Can you update the question with a little bit of your code perhaps? The part that loads the external DLL?

Comment: I confirm that after setting OFF the query returned nothing. Still cannot delete the file.

Comment: I read somewhere that native dll file will not be free (FreeLibrary) after unloading the AppDomain ...

Comment: @John I see many mentions of a DLL not being freed after DllImport unless you used LoadLibrary. However, it does seem like there is a GetModuleHandle function that might be able to get you the external handle to pass to FreeLibrary: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2004/11/12/256199.aspx

Also, I am not sure if this would work, but have you considered creating a wrapper DLL that you would call via DLLImport? And _it_ would call your **Library64.dll** ?

Comment: Do you think I could: GetModuleHandleExA and FreeLibrary when it was initially loaded by .NET on first call. I could then unload all appdomain ...

Comment: I have posted my answer which seems to work. What do you think about that approach?

Comment: @John I think that approach is fine, especially if it is the only thing to work. Have you tried all 3 combinations of _not_ doing steps 3 and/or 4? **1)** don't call `LoadLibrary` to see if call your SQLCLR stored proc again will automatically reload it, **2)** don't unload the AppDomain but still call `LoadLibrary`, and **3)** don't do either? I am curious if we can reduce any of the steps here, and based on my first suggestion not working, the App Domain doesn't seem to be the issue (unless the signature of your method changes, but then you would need to ALTER your managed assembly anyway).

Comment: Step 3 could be remove, it works without but .. I feel better to unload / load  all appdomain. My approach is sufficient as I need maintance window during upgrade time. So it is ok to stop the service.LoadLibrary has to be called always. It will not load again unfortunately. That's why I have two methods (Load/UnLoad)

Comment: @John Ok, but you just said that it is ok to stop the service? I thought you needed to manually unload this DLL because it was _not_ ok to stop the service? Or are you not speaking of the MSSQLSERVER service now? Also, do you mind testing just one more thing? The following unloads all AppDomains and I am curious if it also release the reference to the unmanaged DLL: `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL');`

Comment: well, I cannot stop the process sqlserver but still I have maintance window.. i tried your command. It indeed freed all app domains but native library remained tied up to sqlprocess. So the only option at present we have, is to manage load/unload process manually.

Comment: I have migrated to production where sqlserver 2008R2 is installed. That sql supports only CLR 2.0. I had to rewrite the code and I am afraid my procedure doesn't work. After Unload/Load, .NET seems to have invalid handle and returns memory corruption I am afraid ... Initially I have tested all on 4.5 framework. Probably things have changed since 2.0 ...

Comment: @John What did you specify as the target framework version? You can use up to 3.5 for SQL Server 2008 R2. I don't see why this wouldn't work, the blog post that had the example code is from 2004, and v4 of the CLR hadn't come out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done and what seems to work. Please tell me if it is wrong to do this..

I have added two additional CLR storedprocedure like these:

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static void asdUnloadLibrary()
{
    try
    {
        var hMod = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (GetModuleHandleExA(0, "Engine64.dll", ref hMod))
        {
            while (FreeLibrary(hMod))
            { }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Library not found");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    return;
}

[SqlProcedure]
public static void asdLoadLibrary()
{
    try
    {
        var hMod = IntPtr.Zero;
        LoadLibrary("Engine64.dll"); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    return;
}
```

Now ... In case I want to copy to server a new native DLL file I will:

```
1) Execute asdUnloadLibrary stored procedure. This will unload the dll.
2) Then, I can copy another version of dll to system folder
3) Then I can (but I think it is not necessary) do it:

ALTER DATABASE TEST SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE TEST SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO

4) Execute asdLoadLibrary
```

And Now the original UDF function works again as expected ...

Comment: John, I updated my answer to include this suggestion that was originally just in a comment I made on my answer. I also added a link to this answer for anyone looking for the exact code.